# How to structure a user story for an application module?

Tags: backlog

How do I write user story to create, update, view, cancel for trips? Is it needed one user story "Create Trip" with 4 acceptance criteria (create, update, view, cancel) inside "Create Trip"? Or 4 separate user stories like: Create Trip (create acceptance criteria), Update Trip (update acceptance criteria), View Trip (view acceptance criteria), Cancel Trip (cancel acceptance criteria)?

Need an answer how to structure a story.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.